# python&unity3d: Websocket stability

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, websocket

I'm creating an application in Unity3d that communicates with python's websockets library. My python script is as following:

```
from __future__ import division
import asyncio
import websockets
import time
import os
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
from read import CustOPCLib
import socket
from jsonsocket import Client,Server

class SubHandler(object):
    def data_change(self, handle, node, val, attr):
        print("Python: New data change event", handle, node, val, attr)

    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        print("Data received: ",val)

    def event(self, handle, event):
        print("Python: New event", handle, event)


p = CustOPCLib()
async def hello(websocket, path):
    p.connect() #my own custom library
    while True:
        datastring = p.opcjson()             #this is a jsonstring
        await websocket.send(datastring)
        #print("> {}".format(datastring))
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '127.0.0.1', 8765)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

my json string is as following:

```
{
    "Index": 709953575,
    "Moto": true,
    "Start": false,
    "StartWINCC": false,
    "Stop": false,
    "StopWINCC": false,
    "Tag1": true,
    "Tag2": false
}
```

This is the string i want to send to Unity. In Unity3d I've made the following script that used the Concurrentqueue from mono. The script works accordingly, the problem i have however, is that i get alot of null values from the websocket.
my Unity3d script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading;

public class ConcurrentQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
{
    class Node
    {
        public T Value;
        public Node Next;
    }

    Node _head = new Node();
    Node _tail;
    int _count;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public ConcurrentQueue()
    {
        _tail = _head;
    }

    public ConcurrentQueue(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : this()
    {
        foreach (T item in enumerable)
            Enqueue(item);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        var node = new Node { Value = item };

        Node oldTail = null;

        bool update = false;
        while (!update)
        {
            oldTail = _tail;
            var oldNext = oldTail.Next;

            // Did tail was already updated ?
            if (_tail == oldTail)
            {
                if (oldNext == null)
                {
                    // The place is for us
                    update = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _tail.Next, node, null) == null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // another Thread already used the place so give him a hand by putting tail where it should be
                    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _tail, oldNext, oldTail);
                }
            }
        }
        // At this point we added correctly our node, now we have to update tail. If it fails then it will be done by another thread
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _tail, node, oldTail);

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool TryDequeue(out T value)
    {
        value = default(T);
        bool advanced = false;
        while (!advanced)
        {
            Node oldHead = _head;
            Node oldTail = _tail;
            Node oldNext = oldHead.Next;

            if (oldHead == _head)
            {
                // Empty case ?
                if (oldHead == oldTail)
                {
                    // This should be false then
                    if (oldNext != null)
                    {
                        // If not then the linked list is mal formed, update tail
                        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _tail, oldNext, oldTail);
                    }
                    value = default(T);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = oldNext.Value;
                    advanced = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _head, oldNext, oldHead) == oldHead;
                }
            }
        }

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool TryPeek(out T value)
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        Node first = _head.Next;
        value = first.Value;
        return true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _count = 0;
        _tail = _head = new Node();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalGetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalGetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalGetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> InternalGetEnumerator()
    {
        Node myHead = _head;
        while ((myHead = myHead.Next) != null)
        {
            yield return myHead.Value;
        }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        T[] dest = array as T[];
        if (dest == null)
            return;
        CopyTo(dest, index);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] dest, int index)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> e = InternalGetEnumerator();
        int i = index;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            dest[i++] = e.Current;
        }
    }

    public T[] ToArray()
    {
        T[] dest = new T[_count];
        CopyTo(dest, 0);
        return dest;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return _syncRoot; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return _count == 0;
        }
    }
}

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    class OpcJson
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public bool Moto { get; set; }
        public bool Start { get; set; }
        public bool StartWINCC { get; set; }
        public bool Stop { get; set; }
        public bool StopWINCC { get; set; }
        public bool Tag1 { get; set; }
        public bool Tag2 { get; set; }
    }
    //variables
    static readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    public string receivedFromServer;
    WebSocket w = new WebSocket(new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:8765"));
    public Text testert;
    public Image moto;
    public Image start;
    public Image startwincc;
    public Image stop;
    public Image stopwincc;
    public Image tag1;
    public Image tag2;
    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator StartWebsocket()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(w.Connect());
        //w.SendString("Hi there");
        //int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string reply = w.RecvString();
            if (reply != null)
            {
                //Debug.Log(reply);
                queue.Enqueue(reply);
                //receivedFromServer = reply;
                //Debug.Log("Received: " + reply);
                //w.SendString("Hi there" + i++);
            }
            if (w.error != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Error: " + w.error);
                break;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        w.Close();
    }
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        w.Close();
    }
    IEnumerator JsonObjectSetter(float waitforsecods)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            queue.TryDequeue(out receivedFromServer);
            //string s = receivedFromServer;
            //Debug.Log(s);
            if(receivedFromServer == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("I'm null");
            }
            else
            {
                var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpcJson>(receivedFromServer);
                testert.text = results.Index.ToString();
                if (results.Moto == true)
                {
                    moto.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    moto.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.Start == true)
                {
                    start.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    start.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.StartWINCC == true)
                {
                    startwincc.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    startwincc.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.Stop == true)
                {
                    stop.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    stop.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.StopWINCC == true)
                {
                    stopwincc.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    stopwincc.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.Tag1 == true)
                {
                    tag1.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    tag1.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }

                if (results.Tag2 == true)
                {
                    tag2.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                }
                else
                {
                    tag2.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitforsecods);
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartWebsocket());
        StartCoroutine(JsonObjectSetter(1));
    }
}
```

as you can see, I've made an if/else statement in my JsonObjectSetter method. Everytime the string is null after a dequeue, it prints out "I'm null", and if its not null, it gets used to set an image to a color according to the value.
How can i make it so I won't get any nulls anymore?

Edit 1: during a 7-minute test I've counted 49 nulls. This is quite a big issue to be honest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!
The problem was that my python script had a `time.sleep()` which lasts 1 second, changed it to 0.1, and changed the WaitForSecods in the Unityscript to 0.25f. This totally fixed my problem. Kind of stupid that I didn't think of this before posting it on Stackoverflow.